# Disable combobox dropdown when the binded property is marked as readonly

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, propertygrid, readonly-attribute

I have a service which sets a property's ReadOnly attribute to true/ false in runtime, so the user will not be able to change the property value in propertyGrid.

The service is useful when the property is being edit in a text editor.
However, some of my editors are comboboxs.
I want the dropdown to be disabled when I set the property to readonly- meaning the user will be able to see the selected item in the combobox, but when he clicks the arrow next to the combobox to see the options nothing will happend. this is not working with the current implementation. I guess I need to use a different attribute to the property. I've tried to change the "EditableAttribute" of the property but it doesn't work....
The code I am using to change readonly property:

```
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)[property];
        ReadOnlyAttribute attribute = (ReadOnlyAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = attribute.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(attribute, value);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the public property IsReadOnly instead of the field?

Comment: It does not matter, since for the text editor the above code does work....

Comment: Have you implemented this in MVVM, Did you tried binding the property in VM to `IsEnabled` property of `Combobox` in view.

Comment: Yes, and it would work.I need the the implementation to be in the model layer, meaning I want to change only the binnded property attributes. I don't know if this is possible...

Answer (score 0):

In standard WPF ComboBox, `IsReadOnly` has effect only when `IsEditable = true`, but does not prevent the user from selecting values. it just makes the editable text box read-only.

To completely prevent the control from selection you should use **`IsEnabled = false`**.

Comment: Is there any attribute of the binnded property itself that I can change so the combobox will be disabled, without binding the combobox isEnabled property?

Comment: @mmm I cant find any such attribute.  Let me do a  quick search  on it.